# git clone "you appear to have cloned an empty repository" but it's not empty, pull says "couldn't find remote ref master"

Tags: windows, git, git-clone, git-pull

I'm trying to set up a vanilla new separate repository for the first time with git 2.37.1 on two W10 systems using drive mapping but I can't find any answered questions that fit my case given my novicitry. :-) Sorry the format is messed up, I did 4 spaces in front of code but most code lines ignore that for some reason.

Spent hours looking at other similar questions, but they all seem to say that there are no commits in the remote repository I'm trying to clone, which is not true. There are lots of commits.

I created a git repository on System1 and it works.

```
 git ls-tree --full-tree --name-only -r HEAD
```

shows all my files (with lots of commits)

```
 git show HEAD
```

shows

```
 commit 557...27d (HEAD -> master)  
 # and the diff between the latest and previous commit
```

And

```
 git branch -a
```

shows

```
* master
```

No branches, no complexity, no nothing

I go to System2, and create my repo directory, cd into it, then

```
git init  
git remote add origin s:/cap2office # that's my mapped System1 repository)
git pull origin master
```

I get:  `fatal: couldn't find remote ref master`

```
git remote
```

I get: `origin`

```
git branch -a
```

shows nothing

```
git ls-remote
```

shows: `From s:/cap2office`

I also tried:

```
git clone s:/cap2office
```

and it says

```
Cloning into 'cap2office'...  
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

I know I'm missing some trivial magic command, but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: This suggests some sort of weirdness with drive mapping. There is definitely Windows weirdness with drive mapping, but since I don't use Windows, I'm not sure what the details are; find a Windows guru to find out.

Comment: You can use `git clone` directly on System 2, no need for `git init` there. It will pull the repo with branches and all.

Comment: "System1" and "system2" are two different machines, right ? the original repo on system1 was created using the first PC (as opposed to: mounting `s:cap2office/` on system2, and creating the repo on `system1` from a shell opened from the second system), then you try to access the same files from the second PC ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not cloning a repository, you are trying to clone the working directory of a git clone.

The git repository is stored in the `.git` folder inside the working directory.

Try this:

```
git remote add origin s:/cap2office/.git
```

Comment: Didn't work.  
Tried "git remote add origin s:/cap2office/.git"  
Then in empty c:\cap2office, typed "git clone s:/cap2office/.git  
Got: Cloning into 'cap2office'...  
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.  

So then I tried  
git pull s:/cap2office/.git master  
and got
    fatal: not a git repositoy (or any of the parent directories): .git  

So I tried:  
git pull s:/cap2office master  
and got
    fatal: couldn't find remote ref master

Just to make sure, I can see all the files under S:\cap2office\.git in Windows Explorer

Sorry about the formatting

Comment: Sorry, for some reason, putting 2 spaces at the end of the line does't break.  
I just tried zipping the entire repository on System1 and copied to System2, unpacked it, and git seems to work.  There should be a better way to do it than that. Copying just the .git folder and subdirectories didn't work tho, what else do I need? I thought everything was in the repository under .git?

Comment: Something else strange: On System2 if I cd to S:/cap2office (the repository on System1) then git log, I get "fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet." But if I do the same command to c:/cap2office (locally on System2) as a result of zipping all the System1 cap2office repository files over, it works. It's as though git on System2 is not able to read correctly over the VPN/RDP link from System1.

Answer (score 0):

On system 2, instead of doing `git init` then `git remote add` and `git pull`, do just this:

```
git clone s:/cap2office/.git
```

or if you're in Git Bash, sometimes the colon does not work so you need

```
git clone s/cap2office/.git
```

Then you can `cd` to the folder where it was cloned and do the usual `git status`, `git checkout`, change stuff, commit, and push to the remote.

Comment: Still doesn't work. git clone s:/cap2office/.git  
results in "you appear to have cloned an empty repository."  
It's as though System2 is not correctly seeing files in System1.  
But Windows Explorer and the cmd window both see the files.

Comment: One other thing... System2 is actually far away and I VPN to it using ui.com and I set up the drive mapping with RDP. Perhaps there's an incompatibility somewhere in the complexity of git/VPN/RDP which causes git to not work. This sounds like a bug someplace.

Comment: I think I've figured out the problem, reposted a clearer question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73024120/git-incompatible-with-microsoft-networking-using-vpn-rdp-tsclient