# git incompatible with Microsoft networking using VPN/RDP/TSclient

Tags: git, vpn, rdp

I've asked this question before, but I was so new, I think I was misunderstanding the root cause of the problem which I think I now understand (see [git clone "you appear to have cloned an empty repository" but it's not empty, pull says "couldn't find remote ref master"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73013703/git-clone-you-appear-to-have-cloned-an-empty-repository-but-its-not-empty-pu) ).

I've tried what several people suggested and nothing works, and at this point I think it's due to an incompatibility between how git accesses a repository over a network, and the M$ VPN/RDP/TSclient facility for networking. Would this be a bug that git developers would like to know about?

I've got System1 and System2 are miles apart and so are not on the same LAN, and so have connected them using the ui.com VPN and M$ RDP/TSclient. I can map one drive onto the other system and so I can transfer files back and forth. But when git accesses (like for cloning) using the mapped drives, it thinks the repository at the other end is empty. In addition, when git inits the .git area, it makes .git hidden which caused some problems as well until I figured that out and unhid it.

I suppose the only other thing I can try is OneDrive or something, does anybody have any suggestions other than that?

Comment: You yourself just proved this isn't the case. Before blaming `M$` consider that Stack Overflow itself is a .NET application developed and running on Windows servers by Windows developers, using Git from the start. We can't guess what's going on with your network, your VPN configuration or your firewalls. Or what RDP and terminal services even have to do with *git*. RDP isn't a networking protocol, it's a Remote Desktop Protocol running over TCP. Git needs TCP, not RDP

Comment: If your company network blocks you, contact the company IT admins. If you set up the network yourself, only you know what's wrong, what ports you enabled. `using the ui.com VPN` in that case *you* need to open the TCP ports needed by whatever Git server you installed on the remote machine.

Comment: Frankly, it would be far safer to use a hosted Git service like Github than trying to create and secure your own VPN. Private Github repositories are free for individuals.

Comment: I don't understand why I can copy files, but git doesn't work. And I thought the whole point of VPN over ui.com (or tools like it) is so that ports don't need to be opened in the firewall, right?

Elsewhere it looks like OneDrive is a bad solution, but Google Drive may work so I'm going to go down that path.

Comment: And that's why you should use Github. If you can't understand the difference between TCP, git, file shares and RDP, you can't install and secure your own VPN. You aren't copying files between machines right now at all. You're opening a terminal and copying stuff out of it at 1/100th the speed of an actual connection or copying from a shared folder. You **don't** need RDP to copy files from one Windows machine to another

Comment: `I thought the whole point of VPN over ui.com (or tools like it) is so that ports don't need to be opened in the firewall, right?` wrong. It's so you can connect in the first place, without exposing your machines to the public internet. VPN means Virtual Private Network. You're creating something that looks like (Virtual) a private network between your machine/network and another. VPN software doesn't allow just anything to cross from one network to another. Neither do the routers or firewalls at the two networks

Comment: I guess I really don't understand the configuration I have. If VPN doesn't allow those crossings, how am I able to transfer a file between the two systems? I'll look at Github, maybe that's the solution. It's for Civil Air Patrol which is a charity so maybe they'll give us a break. Thank you!

Comment: Possibly related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/304365/tsclient-folder-empty-despite-selecting-local-driv.html (note that there's no answer though, it just notes that there's some kind of group policy feature involved here). The fact that marking a folder hidden or unhidden changes things means you're hitting some kind of MS security glitch or something similar. In any case, if you can use a sharing host like GitHub, that's probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. It just seemed to me if I could see a letter-drive on one system pointing to the drive on the other, and I could transfer files, seems like git should see the files the same way but I guess not. Will look into github too, it's for a non-profit so maybe they'll take pity on us. :-) Also Google Drive looks like it might work, but we'd have to work out how not to have collisions.

Answer (score 1):

I posted to the git list, and got the answer of how to fix this problem. Somebody speculated that git thinks that S:\ is a local drive and is trying to create hardlinks which of course fail. So if I `git clone --no-hardlinks` that makes it work!